# merging and removing duplicates in two csv's without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have a test output csv that looks like the following;

```
test1   test success
test2   test failed
regtest failed to build
```

column 1 contains unique strings and column 2 contains one of the following three strings; test success, test failed, failed to build.

I run this test every so often on new builds and I want to compare the csv from the latest test with the previous test.
I would like to produce a new csv containing all the tests whose state(column 2) has changed. Preferably in the format of;

```
TestName OldState NewState
```

Here is my current attempt which gets all the differences between the two files but it looks like this;

```
test1   test success
test2   test failed
regtest failed to build
test2   test success
```

I need a way to merge the second test2 with the first one so it looks like this;

```
test1   test success
test2   test failed      test success
regtest failed to build
```

My current code;

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as t1, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as t2, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as t3, open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as t4:
    fileOne = t1.readlines()
    fileTwo = t2.readlines()
    fileThree = t3.readlines()
    fileFour = t4.readlines()

with open(sys.argv[3], 'w') as outFile:
    for line in fileTwo:
        if line not in fileOne:
            outFile.write("From File 2," + line)

    for line in fileFour:
        if line not in fileThree:
            outFile.write("\r\nFrom File 1," + line)
```

Comment: **edit** im using python 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in your csv has a key value pair, so it makes sense to write your csv to a dictionary, and then you can easily compare both values based on keys

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as t1, open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as t2:
    # Convert lines of Csv to list
    reader1 = list(csv.reader(t1))
    reader2 = list(csv.reader(t2))

# Create a dictionary of key value pairs for t1
fileOne_dict = {col[0]: [col[1]] for col in reader1}

# compare values based on keys and append if different
for col in reader2:
    if fileOne_dict.get(col[0]):
        if fileOne_dict[col[0]][0] != col[1]:
            fileOne_dict[col[0]].append(col[1])
    else:
        fileOne_dict[col[0]] = ["", col[1]]

out = [[key]+value for key, value in fileOne_dict.items()]
print(out)

with open ('diff.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    writer.writerows(out)
```

This should leave you with a dictionary containing the information you want

Comment: When I use this code I get the string {"T":"e R R R e e e e e e e e...,"P":"B"}?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, thought you would get a list of values from reading a csv rather than a string. Ill append the code

Comment: I'm getting: KeyError: 'T' from line 9

Comment: try copying the code again, you may have missed an edit, seems fine on my end, if it still doesnt, post your csv

Comment: you were right, I had something missed typed. But got a new error for you :) It seems to throw an error if a new test appears in the second file that isn't already in the first file

Comment: thats to be expected as the code is looking for a key in fileOne_dict that does not exist.  we can check that the key is present first using dict.get(key), which returns None if it doesnt find anything

Comment: I think we are almost there. Using;
with open ('diff.csv', 'w') as outFile:
   outFile.write(json.dumps(fileOne_dict))

I get a continuous line rather than the original layout
eg; test1 Pass Failed test 2 Pass test 3 FailedToBuild etc

Comment: so dict to csv doesnt seem very easy to do, probably would have been better to use lists instead of dictionaries but whatever, made it so it outputs a list of lists and then can easily write it to csv, works on my end now anyway

Comment: Thanks for this. The format is now correct but it isn't correctly identifying where the status has changed. In some cases (eg where there is a new test in the second file) there is no status next to the test name. In others it is adding an incorrect status?

Comment: OK... I cant see your errors.  you should post how to replicate an error if you want anyone else to help fix it.

Comment: `File 1:   
Test_ALG_1,Test success   
Test_ALG_2,Test failed   
Test_ALG_3,Failed to build exe   
Test_ALG_4,Test success  
Test_ALG_5,Test success`

Comment: `File 2:  
Test_ALG_1,Test failed   
Test_ALG_2,Test failed  
Test_ALG_3,Failed to build exe  
Test_ALG_4,Test success  
Test_ALG_6,Test success`

Comment: `Output:  
Test_ALG_1,Test failed   
Test_ALG_2,Test failed, Test failed  
Test_ALG_3,Failed to build exe   
Test_ALG_4,Test success  
Test_ALG_5,   ,Test success`

These are the examples of the 2 input files and 1 output file @Mr_Nitrogen